# Keep element fixed while absolutely positioned in a scrolling element

Tags: html, css

I have written a code snippet so you understand what I mean better. I have a scrollable area in a grid. I would like to have an element in the bottom left corner to add a new item to the list.

I would like it to be positioned relative to the scrollable element as it will have a dynamic width which is why I cant just use position fixed, I dont want to be positioning it from the edge of the screen.

I dont want it to scroll with the background either. Is there any way thats not hacky to get around this?

```css
.page {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: auto 1fr auto;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: red;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  position: relative;
}

.item {
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid black;
  height: 90px;
  background-color: blue;
}

.header {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.add {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 16px;
  right: 16px;
  background-color: green;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="page">

  <div class="header"></div>

  <div class="scrollable">
    <div class="add">+</div>
    
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
    <div class="item"></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer"></div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use position `sticky` to "stick" an element to a scrollable element. Position sticky fluctuates the position of an element between `static` and `fixed` depending on the scroll position.

Since you cannot use `bottom` with `position: sticky`, you have to use `top` instead, and `calc()` the margin from the top using the known height of your button, in this case `30px`.

```
.add {
  height: 30px;
  position: sticky;
  float: right; /* go to the right */
  right: 16px;
  top: calc(100% - 30px - 16px);
}
```

Comment: This isnt positioning it relative to the scrollable area though, this is just guessing how left the element is going to and positioning it relative to the side of the screen isnt it?

Comment: Not exactly. Try removing the `transform` and look at what happens. Then it really is relative to the scrollable area, but is placed at the top left corner of the scrollable container. All i'm doing with the translation is I am moving that add button relative to its default position (the top left corner of the scrollable container).

Comment: ah yes i see what you mean, is there a way to set it relative to the bottom right corner? transform 100% is using the width of the element so its not going far, and pixels isnt as reliable as i would like

Comment: Yeah I agree. Well, you could always use Js to get the computed style of the scrollable container and use that in addition with the translation, but if I was building a site I would not use that. I'm just trying to think of a CSS-only solution now.

Comment: Ok, I've edited my response, check the `.add` class.

Comment: this didn't work for me